# Why did Bloodsport say, "That's the word" here?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, the-suicide-squad-2021

In *The Suicide Squad* (2021), Bloodsport and his crew reaches the shore:

> Peacemaker: Don't they have blockades at the city limits?
>
> Bloodsport: **That's the word**.
>
> Peacemaker: How we getting in? Especially with Charlie the Tuna here.

Why did Bloodsport say, "That's the word" here?

Comment: Because that was the rumor, or whatever intelligence they had said. The word on the street is…

Comment: You might get better traction if you post on [ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) or [ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com) instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted by Jon Custer in his comment, a common phrase is "That's the word on the street", indicating that's what current news, rumor, or other information is. Bloodsport, assuming familiarity with the phrase, simply cuts it off to "That's the word", which can make less sense if you're not familiar with that phrase's use.